# Как обратиться к значениям по ключу словаря?

Tags: python, json, словари

```
[
{
    "503fcf1190e77fc73cb196341195915d": {
        "name": 2,
        "time": "2019-12-14-20-16",
        "words": 2
    }
},
{
    "6574e5574fe2ac73af6b51f8845836d5": {
        "name": 2,
        "time": "2019-12-10-21-51",
        "words": 2
    }
},
{
    "ac1f7ad71643ef8017807f8056fd4c04": {
        "name": 2,
        "time": "2019-12-04-21-51",
        "words": 3
    }
}
]
```

Есть файл json такого вида. Мне нужно обратить к ключу 'words' в каждом словаре. Как это сделать максимально короткой конструкцией? У меня получается только с костылями.

```
            for elem in loaded: #loaded - выгруженный файл, список со словарями
                for hash in elem:
                    tags = elem[hash]['words']
```

Comment: почему же костыль, вполне хорошая реализация

Comment: наставник говорит что можно писать короче и это у меня не ООП) вот интересно каким еще способом можно это записать

Comment: Каждый словарь в списке всегда состоит из одного ключа?

Comment: короче в плане вложенного цикла, или в строчках?

Comment: да, словарь в списке всегда состоит из одного ключа.
короче в плане меньше циклов, так то конечно можно циклы в одну строку записать, но будет не так читабельно